# How to convert EBCDIC with Spanish accent to English in RUST

Tags: rust, ebcdic

If the string contains truly Spanish accents in UTF8, I could use unidecode()

```
let x = unidecode("ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ");    
println!("reading file: {}", x);
// output = SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy
```

However, I am working mainframe output file in EBCDIC format, if I view it in redhat terminal, I see "Mu�oz". If I ftp the file to OSX and view it in TextEdit, I see "MuÒoz". There are some encoding in the TextEdit when viewing ....

The utf8 Spanish accents should be C392 in Hex, but I got F1 from mainframe file. How can I convert � to Ò and then O, and for all other Spanish accents?

+++

utf8 Spanish accents = Ò = C392 (Hex) = ﺃφ

EBCDIC Spanish accents = � = F1 (Hex) = ﹼ

If I use unidecode(), it changes "Mu�oz" to "Muoz". I want to convert "Mu�oz" to "MuoOz".

=======

updated on 2023.05.03

========

I tried both  ISO_8859_10 encoding ...it converted "Mu�oz" to "Muïŋ―oz". Now, I am questioning whether it is EBCDIC encoded file that I am getting ...

```
let file_in = File::open("infile").unwrap();
    let mut file_out = File::create("outfile").unwrap();

    let mut decoded_stream = DecodeReaderBytesBuilder::new()
        .encoding(Some(ISO_8859_10))
        .build(file_in);

    std::io::copy(&mut decoded_stream, &mut file_out).unwrap();
```

Comment: Do you mean [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)?

Comment: There is a [crate to convert to ascii](https://docs.rs/encoding8/latest/encoding8/ebcdic/index.html), but I don't think it supports characters like Ò

Comment: Yes ... EBCDIC. I just updated the post. If I could convert the EBCDIC Spanish accents to utf8 Spanish accents, I could use unidecode() to convert them to English.

Comment: Perhaps the ebcdic crate: https://docs.rs/encoding8/latest/encoding8/ebcdic/index.html

Comment: @PaulDempsey that crate also only converts to ascii, but it's unclear to me whether that restriction makes it un-useable for OP

Comment: But why do you want a Ò? The real name is "Muñoz", that is with an `ñ`, that is 0xF1 in Latin1 or Windows-1252 encoding.

Comment: There are multiple encodings under the EBCDIC umbrella. This page may be somewhat helpful: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Character_Encodings/Code_Tables/EBCDIC/EBCDIC_1047 (since you're talking about Spanish accents, the 1047 (Latin1) set is probably the one for the OP).

Comment: @rodrigo, you are right. When viewing the name in terminal, I see "Mu�oz". After ftp the file to OSX, I see "MuÒoz" in TextEdit.  the correct spelling should be "Muñoz". It looks like TextEdit just convert the "�" to "Ò". Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: So you might want to try https://docs.rs/encoding_rs/latest/encoding_rs/mem/fn.decode_latin1.html

Comment: hum ... it doesn't seem the EBCDIC crate is working for me ... @Pitaj,  will try encoding_rs::mem::decode_latin1

Comment: What I think it is happening is that the FTP is converting automatically the EBCDIC to Latin1 so you now have a 0xF1=`ñ` there. Then when you type the file to the terminal it tries to read it as UTF-8 (`LANG` env. maybe), but 0xF1 is not a valid UTF-8 sequence so you get a substitution character `�`. But when you try to open it with TextEdit it interprets the file as `mac_roman` by default, where the 0xF1 byte stands for `Ò`. To get the proper characters you should read the file using the Latin1 encoding.

Comment: @Rodrigo, thanks for the info. currently, it is using >> let s =  String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer); I will try to use >>>
let s =  String:: latin1_to_string(&buffer);

Comment: @rodrigo, any ideas on the conversion result? See "updated on 2023.05.03" from the original post for detail.

Comment: @CalL: Funny, the sequence `ïŋ―` in ISO_8859_10 is `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD`, that is the UTF-8 encoding for a literal `�`! Note that the `�` is a substitution character, used when you read a wrong UTF-8 byte sequence for example, but you cannot convert back the `�` to the original byte sequence. Maybe you could try and post an hex dump of the file (with the command `od -tx1 file.txt`) and the code you are using to read it?